# Has wit.ai stopped development on android-sdk

Tags: android, ios, chatbot, wit.ai

I'm currently looking into NLP and Chatbot frameworks for a personal project of mine when I ran across wit.ai. While it seems very intuitive and developer friendly while also being completely free I do feel doubtful about their android-SDK repo here: https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-android-sdk. 
The project I have is based on an Android app so a stale SDK repo is kind of a red flag which is why I'm a bit concerned.

Have they stopped developing it because the iOS one seems pretty up to date and maintained?

Answer (score 1):

Are the iOS changes new features or just SDK updates? I've not noticed many changes in the API.

Also, have you considered using Api.ai

Comment: Just SDK updates.
No, I haven't checked out API.ai. Thanks for mentioning it, I'll take a look